# The bash source command does not work with pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

There are 3 files (`a`, `b` and `c`), all with `777` permissions:

```
$ ls
a  b  c
```

The above files have the following contents:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash
export A=aaa
$ cat b
#!/bin/bash
source ./a
echo $A
$ cat c
#!/bin/bash
source ./a | >> log
echo $A
```

The only difference between `b` and `c` is `| >> log`:

```
$ diff b c
2c2
< source ./a
---
> source ./a | >> log
```

When `b` is executed it outputs the expected `aaa`:

```
$ ./b
aaa
```

When `c` is executed it outputs, for me, an unexpected blank row instead of the expected `aaa`, and the `log` file that script `c` created is empty:

```
$ ./c

$ cat log
$
```

Clearly, there is something about `source` and `|` that I have yet to learn.

Could someone please enlighten me regarding why `c` does not output `aaa`?

Comment: What's the use of `| >> log`?

Comment: In your file `c`, when you do `source ./a | >> log`, the statement `source ./a` doesn't output anything on stdout, so it makes sense that you get nothing in `log`.

Comment: This is a simplification of a larger script, where each line outputs to a log file. Whether or not there will be any output from each line is not known. I know there are different ways of solving logging, but I would like to know why this solution does not work.

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you very much! That would explain it, that comment is worthy as an answer I think.

Comment: @oguzismail That's too strong. `d` *can* be executed in the current evironment, if the `lastpipe` option is in effect. But by default, *all* commands in a pipe are executed in a subshell. (You may be thinking of `ksh`.)

Answer (score 6):

Use a process substitution instead of a pipeline:

```
source ./a > >(tee -a log)
```

That way your `source` command runs in the original shell.

Alternately, stop creating a pipeline at all:

```
source ./a >>log
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, the first command in a pipeline will always be executed in a subshell, so any variables that it imports are lost. But a pipeline is not what you want in the first place. With  `foo | >> file`, it redirects the output of `foo` into a null command, then the output of the null command (which is null) is appended to the file. I'm not sure why Bash allows the second command in the pipeline to be null when there's a redirection.

You want `command >> file`, i.e.

```
$ cat c
#!/bin/bash
source ./a >> log
echo $A
```

Although `source ./a` doesn't produce any output.