# How to source /etc/apache2/envvars within python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I want to source this /etc/apache2/envvars before running apache2 -V command which is giving me this output wihtout soruce

```
user@ubuntu16:~$ apache2 -V
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.045086 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.045115 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.045142 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.053712 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.053860 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Sep 14 05:01:39.053878 2021] [core:warn] [pid 13942] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00543: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

running the command **source /etc/apache2/envvars** from the terminal is making the above warn go away but I want to do this from the python script as I am calling the **apache2 -V** from my python script to do some parsing of the output.

I am using the command execfile to source the file but I am getting the error and not sure how to resolve this issue. Is there any right wayt to soruce this /etc/apache2/envvars file within python script

```
root@ubuntu16:/home/virsec# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Mar  1 2021, 11:38:31)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile("/etc/apache2/envvars")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/etc/apache2/envvars", line 4
    unset HOME
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execfile` is for executing Python code, not for shell variables. I guess you found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040659/11384184). What it meant is not to execfile the `envvars` file, but to execfile some Python code, passing the required variables in the `globals` parameter. Cf [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile).

But you can't **source** from Python because it is a shell built-in. cf [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

Can you consider running this command instead :

```sh
$ source envvars && python so69188563.py
```

with

```sh
# file: envvars
export ARYAMAN=1718
```

```py
# file: so69188563.py
import subprocess

outcome = subprocess.run(["python", "fake_apache2.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if outcome.returncode != 0:
    print("error !")
else:
    print(outcome.stdout)  # do something with it
```

```py
# file: fake_apache2.py
import os
print(os.environ.get("ARYAMAN", "MISSING!"))  # print the value or missing
```

or put it in a file :

```
# !/bin/sh
# file: run.sh
source envvars
echo $ARYAMAN
python so69188563.py
```

and execute it normally : `./run.sh`

Either way you get `b'1718\n'` which proves that `fake_apache2.py` sees the envvar.

Some details on my solution :

- I assumed you did not want to set them all in the command line, like `export ARYAMAN=1718; python so69188563.py`
- You can't do something like `source envvar && python so69188563.py` because of the shell uses subprocess for each individual commands, they do not share environment variables (cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60653561/11384184) but the answers are bad)
- The variable in the `envvar` must be `export`ed, cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993885/why-cant-python-see-environment-variables)
- I did not want to parse (Ba)sh syntax like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503719/11384184) does